# Can you get a very good AUC-ROC score despite predicting all rows to have the same probability?

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, roc

On the test set of a binary classification problem, the p25, p50 and p75 of the predictions are very close to each other (e.g. 0.123).

Is it possible that my model can achieve a high AUC-ROC (e.g. 0.85) despite giving the same probability prediction for almost the rows?

The data is imbalanced.

Comment: If it is a imbalanced class it can happen

Comment: "very close to each other", or "same for nearly all rows"? Some more details on the distribution of predicted probabilities, please. Also, what kind of model?

Comment: ROC only cares about ranking. So 0.1231 and 0.1232 are as far apart as -100 and +1000: 1 rank. Can you show the actual values?